# Update and insert while synchronization Microsoft synchronization?

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

Microsoft synchronization implemented is as follows:

1. I have Sql server DB with a table “Products” this table currently contains only one record as shown. 
   [image]
2. I then synchronize this with my client which is a Sql Compact edition (CE) so after I synchronize with the client the table in the client will also contain the same as above
   I use the LocalProvider-Sql compact edition and RemoteProvider-Sql Server DB.
   [image]
3. Now , I change the SERVER “Products” table column entry “Name” – “PC” to “UBUNTUPC” so my server DB table looks like this and then there was an update on the products table .
   [image]
4. Now, the table “Products” at the client sdf file is also changed this Products table contains two new records added to it the Client SDF Prodcuts table is as shown below.
   [image]
5. Now If I synchronize both the DB’s with the LocalProvider as the SDF file(CE) and the RemoteProvider as the Sql Server with the sync direction as UploadAndDownload then 
   Table in the client gets updated with these values shown below and the other two records are lost .
   [image]

How do I update from "PC" to "UBANTUPC" value in my client sdf at the same time I want to add “Laptop”, “Frantest” at the server products table ?

UPDATE: I have written the code where in I set the LocalProvider and the RemoteProvider manually. Below is the provider code

```
syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlCeSyncProvider("OfflineDataScope", clientConn); 
syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("OfflineDataScope", serverConn);
```

Comment: In order to help you debug the problem, it's probably a good idea to set up some event handlers. Using ApplyChangeFailed will allow you to check for conflicts for example.

Comment: which provider are you using? did you hand code the sync or did you use the Local Database Cache Wizard?

Comment: I have written the code where in i set the LocalProvider and the RemoteProvider manually . Below is the provder code

 syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlCeSyncProvider("OfflineDataScope", clientConn);
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("OfflineDataScope", serverConn);